# Report viewer axis range is changing involuntary

Tags: c#, asp.net, charts, reportviewer

At my asp.net project in report viewer I set vertical axis range of my chart to:

Minimum : 0
Maximum : 2,5
Interval: Auto
Interval type: Auto

When I run project at my local, it is OK.

But when I run it at another PC, my vertical axis changes from 2,5 to 25.

I don't know why?

Please help me, i am gonna be crazy..

Comment: [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Please take a number, our telepathic department is busy retrieving the code from another person's brain at the moment.

Comment: how about changing the comma to a dot first? `2.5` because in programming `2,5` are two separate numbers.

Comment: Vertical axis range of the chart must be from 0 to 2,5 and it is at my local PC but at other PC it is from 0 to 25.
what do you mean by "take a number" ?

Comment: i was being sarcastic, didnt you read the "telepathic department" part... i meant post some code mate, we cannot guess whats wrong with a code we cannot see...

Comment: I changed to dot: 2.5 and now it is 25 at my local. 
2,5 is correct.

Comment: but did it change on the server? as you can see, the same issue is now occurring on your local pc. is there any difference between the server and your local pc?

Comment: No, the same exe taking the same data sample from the same path(their own C:\\) nothing is different.
Yes, now it is the same issue here is the better confess:
I used it at a third PC at the server and it works fine like my local PC :) 
what is the problem of this PC I dont know I changed resolutions etc. the same :S

Comment: That PC I dont know why re-arranges axis range of the chart

Comment: I believe the difference between the computers lies in the fact that they have different cultural settings.

Comment: Culturel settings can be MAYBE that pc wants 2.5 instead of 2,5 I will check now

Comment: Yes, it was because of the culturel settings.
At my problem PC charts shown with dots.
Thank you a lot..

Comment: @YusufMert, I have added an answer to help people having the same issue in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that the different computers had different cultural settings. A simple setting change could be a solution, or, if that is out of the question, then separate versions for separate cultures can solve the issue, or, at the part where the settings are initialized the cultural differences can be mended.